# How to restore IE8 Default settings on Windows XP from a remote machine

Tags: windows, pstools

Here is my goal.  This will be run on one Windows XP machine only, for trouble shooting purposes.  We need to be able to remotely execute.

```
psexec \\computername -d -e -u domain\administrator -p password cmd /c "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ResetIEtoDefaults"
```

I have tried and it will not execute.

```
psexec \\computername -d -e -u domain\administrator -p password cmd /c "MicrosoftFixit50195.msi /qn"
```

Ideally I would like to find all the reg keys that are changed when you run the fixes above, but I have searched for hours and have found nothing.

Comment: Is your real question "How do I reset IE from the command line?"

Comment: Affirmative.  I need a way of sitting at my machine and reset IE to its default state on a remote machine.

Comment: Maybe you could edit your question to clarify. It has potential to be excellent Google material.

Comment: Thanks @jscott I did up date the title.  I actually googled my problem and it came up on the first page.

Answer (score 3):

> Ideally I would like to find all the reg keys that are changed when you run the fixes above

You need to run [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) as you run the patches.

Comment: Ok after running the process monitor, I have decided that is not an option considering that it modified 5081 reg key values.  I am back to figuring out why I cannot run either rundll32 with the parameters I have listed nor the msi file on remote xp machines.